# liquibase - An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

Application is failing to start because of the following:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.liquibase(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:94)
```

Liquibase version 3.5.3

classpath in application.yml

```
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
```

Application failed to start:

[image]

The classpath is correct but it is trying to call some method that doesn't exist.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>8.0.25</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <liquibase-core.version>3.5.3</liquibase-core.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/application.yaml</propertyFile>                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have added the liquibase maven dependency and plugin also and I still get the error.

*****UPDATE******
Changed liquibase version to 3.10.0 and I am now getting the following message:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you added liquibase maven plugin indide your pom.xml? Something like this,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>                  
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>                
</plugin>
```

### UPDATE

Seems like issue with `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Change the version to following

```
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

Also update the `liquibase-core` version as well,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
        url: {url}
        user: {username}
        password: {pass}
        enabled: true
```

Comment: I added this and still getting the same error message. What goes in the liquibase.properties file?

Comment: add propertyFile as it is

Comment: I have. But I do not have a liquibase.properties file?!

Comment: I have application.yaml so I added         <propertyFile>src/main/resources/application.yaml</propertyFile>

Comment: It's a version mismatch issue

Comment: find my update.. make sure you add configs in your application.yml like this